Covariant derivative of a function along a curve
I am trying to find the covariant derivative of the function $f(x) = \arccos(\langle x, y\rangle)$ with respect to $x$ along a smooth curve using Christoffel symbols. My working space is $(S^{n},g)$ as a Riemannian manifold. My vectors are in spherical coordinates and the sphere is parametrised by $r(u,v) = (\cos(v)\sin(u), \sin(v)\sin(u)),\cos(u))$ where $u,v$ are the $uv$-plane.
The $c(t):[0,1]\to S^{n}$ is the curve of the great circle with $c(0)=x$ and $c'(0) = v$, i.e.
$$c(t) = \cos(||v||t) \cdot x \,+ \,\sin(||v||t)\cdot\frac{v}{||v||}$$
I am confused as to how to apply the covariant derivative formula onto a function along a curve, rather than a vector field along a curve. The formula I am using, for some vector field $\vec{v}$, is:
$$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}} \vec{v} = \Big[\frac{\partial v^k}{\partial u^i} + v^j\Gamma^k_{ij}\Big]e_k$$
with $e_k$ being the basis of the tangent plane, and $u^i$ still the $uv$-plane.
At this point, I have the Christoffel symbols calculated, and the metric components too, but I cannot make sense of the $v^k$. Every example I find is differentiating some vector field $(\cdot, \cdot, \cdot)$ along a curve, which makes much more sense, but what could be the $\frac{\partial v^k}{\partial u^i}$ of $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} \arccos(\langle c(t), \cdot \rangle)$?

$\nabla_X f$ is just $Xf$ for any tangent vector $X$. This is more or less the definition.

Could you please rephrase this of give an example? How does this translate into practice?

There is a good reason that the covariant derivative with a single Christoffel symbol and  a plus sign in front of it applies only to vector fields $\vec v$ and not to scalar functions $f,. $ The covariant derivative of the latter is just the ordinary partial derivative.

The ordinary derivative of $\arccos(\langle c(t),y \rangle)$ is not part of the tangent bundle of $S^{n}$, that's why here, I was directed to take the covariant derivative. Could someone please clarify?

That user should not have mentioned anything about connections because it’s not necessary here (you’re only differentiating a real-valued function).

Perhaps the confusion arose because you might have been thinking about the gradient vector of a scalar function. You can think of this as the projection of the ambient gradient onto the tangent plane or as the unique tangent vector whose dot product with the tangent vector $\vec v$ gives the directional derivative of the function in the direction of $\vec v$. Either way, no covariant derivatives.

Where did you find this problem? It makes no sense as written.

Thank you to everyone. I was assigned to adapt this paper onto a $S^n$, which amounts to finding the derivative of the distance (in Eqs. 9 and 10) along a curve through Eq. 6 in the paper. I have made it work through orthogonally projecting the classical gradient into the tangent space, but have been trying to figure out how to make it not dependent on being a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
